# Another HTML-Javascript Mishap

Tags: javascript, html

```
function updateScript(){
    var wilson = document.getElementById("wilson");
    var willow = document.getElementById("willow");
    var mighty = document.getElementById("mighty");
}
window.addEventListener("click",function(event){

updateScript();
    console.log(wilson+willow+mighty);
});
```

The console.log doesn't add my values, but here is the object:

```
<input style="text" name="wilson" id="wilson" maxlength="1" size="1">
```

It outputs [object HTMLInputElement][object HTMLInputElement][object HTMLInputElement]

How can this be fixed to add the values? (the input has javascript to prevent letters, only allows numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use .value, this is the correct code for your updateScript():

```
updateScript();
   console.log(wilson.value +willow.value + mighty.value);
});
```

You can learn more about the property:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_option_value.asp

**UPDATE:**
After looking at code, you have a problem with your HTML validation, you had `<head>` tags inside `<body>`, that is a problem and will make your whole code not function right.  You can use HTML validators to check if your code is validating, it needs to be valid before it can even work!

You can put your `<script>` inside the `<head>` tag or in `<body>` tag.

Comment: I just did but the jsbin.com console and the javascript console within the browser show two different outputs. http://jsbin.com/ziruse/1/

Comment: Okay, i fixed it, look at my answer above to see how or you can see the demo at: http://jsbin.com/cemeripikula/1/

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById` returns an object. You need to extract the value.

```
console.log(wilson.value + willow.value + mighty.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to extract the `values` of all the inputs.

here's a working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/bm3eLwL9/